# Why we don't call function with argument?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in asp.net and one question raised in my mind.

Here sample 
(default.aspx page)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btn_Click" />
```

(Code behind)

```
void protected btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Code statement
}
```

So in aspx page button have onclick attribute which call btn_Click function from code-behind file,
So my question is that to call any function we have to pass its argument, and automated generated function has two arguement, so why we don't pass arguments here, please any one help me...

Comment: Try reading about [Handling and Raising Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720046(v=vs.71).aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sender parameter would contain a reference to the control firing the event. In this case, the button.

The [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx) parameter contains the event data pertaining to this event. In this case, the event contains no data, but in other event handlers, this would contain valuable information. The `System.EventArgs` parameter contains additional information about the event that was raised.

In one line "sender" argument is the object that raised the event. The EventArgs argument is extra information passed to the event.

**EDIT:-**

When Button is clicked, the btn_Click event handler will be fired. The "object sender" portion will be a reference to the button which was clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
void protected btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){   //Code statement}
```

above function is an event handler and compiler send the parameters to that handlers at run time automatically on any event

Answer (score 0):

The function is being called with parameters. These parameters are being automatically generated by the .net framework.

The first parameter is the object which calls the event.
The second parameter is arguments passed to the event. These arguments will be different for every event type, and will (hopefully) contain all relevant information relating to that type of event. Eg a mouse leave event will have information on the coordinates of the mouse etc.

Comment: @user3166530 you are welcome, (but just a FYI, this site tries to discourage the thank you messages just so there is less clutter for the next people looking for this info).

Comment: @user3166530 also since I can see you have thanked 3 people already, if someone has provided an answer to your question that satisfies your needs, you should accept one of the answers so the question is marked as answered.